# Issue with update with OleDbConnection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an Update statement with ADO net. I am using Access 2010 and C sharp, but it is not working and it doesn't have me any error.

```
public static OleDbConnection FileConnexion()
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source=..//..//AdoNetTesteRequete//Teste.accdb";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("L'erreur suivante a été rencontrée :" + e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
public void Modifier(Inscription ins)
{
    string req = "UPDATE inscription set  Adresse=@Adresse,Tele=@Tele where Nom=@Nom and Prenom=@Prenom";

    OleDbConnection connexion = FicheConnexion.FileConnexion();

    OleDbCommand conn = new OleDbCommand(req, connexion);

    conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nom", ins.Nom);
    conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenom", ins.Prenom);
    conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adresse", ins.Adresse);
    conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tele", ins.Tele);
    conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connexion.Close();
}
```

Comment: if there is no error than it not able to find proper row to update

Comment: " but it is not working and it doesn't have me any error." - what is the symptom? are you saying that the access database isn't updated? if so, does the row even exist? and if it does: are you sure you're looking in the right file? a classic error here is to look at the file in the project tree, when you should be looking at the file in the build output tree

Comment: side note: `connexion` should be in a `using` block, as should the `OleDbCommand conn` (which should probably be renamed to `cmd` or similar)

Comment: Inscription is a class having (in attribute "string nom, prenom, tile, Adresse  ; int age "and constructors with  nom, per nom, Adresse, age)

Comment: hi, can you please try both solution i given

Comment: The order you add parameters is important with OleDB so Pranay is right.

Comment: Please accept answer if it worked for you....

Answer (score 2):

There might be issue of sequence of parameter.

```
string req = "UPDATE inscription set  Adresse=@Adresse,Tele=@Tele where Nom=@Nom and Prenom=@Prenom";

    OleDbConnection connexion = FicheConnexion.FileConnexion();

    OleDbCommand conn = new OleDbCommand(req, connexion);
    conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adresse", ins.Adresse);
    conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tele", ins.Tele);
    conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nom", ins.Nom);
    conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenom", ins.Prenom);
```

Add parameter in same sequence as in query , might resolve your issue.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to remove the top part - I know you're only suggesting it as a test, but I think there's still a lot of quoting that would need adding - `='{ins.Adresse}'` etc - frankly, it adds more confusion than it solves. I think you're totally right about the order, though - most likely that exactly the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your where statements returns a row.
If there is no error in an update query, it might be simply that there is no corresponding row. In this case ADO.NET will not throw an error.

Check if this returns 0 or 1 :

```
  string req = "UPDATE inscription set  Adresse=@Adresse,Tele=@Tele where Nom=@Nom and Prenom=@Prenom";

using(OleDbConnection connexion = FicheConnexion.FileConnexion())
 {
   using(OleDbCommand conn = new OleDbCommand(req, connexion))
   {
     conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nom", ins.Nom);
     conn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenom", ins.Prenom);

     int count = Convert.ToInt32( conn.ExecuteScalar());
 }
```

If the cound is not 0, than you should look for an error.